# Error with MySQL, DECLARE

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, declare

I am using MySQL v5.0.92 and I'm trying to import some data, but I get an error on declare my variables.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE flag INT;
  DECLARE id INT;


while flag=0 begin
  SET id=(SELECT top 1 user_id 
         FROM ac_user_info WHERE user_id>@id order by user_id)

  INSERT INTO cuddleew_database1.cewp_usermeta(user_id,meta_key,meta_value)
  SELECT id,'first_name',first_name 
  FROM cuddleew_backup.ac_user_info WHERE user_id=@id

  INSERT INTO cuddleew_database1.cewp_usermeta(user_id,meta_key,meta_value)
  SELECT id,'last_name',last_name 
  FROM cuddleew_backup.ac_user_info WHERE user_id=@id

  SET flag=(select case @id when(SELECT MAX(user_id) 
                                FROM cuddleew_bakup.ac_user_info) then 1
     else 0
     END CASE)
  END WHILE
END
```

In MySQL console i get this:

BEGIN DECLARE flag INT;

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE flag INT' at line 2.**

Can you help me with this and tell me what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to change the delimiter

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your delimiter first, so the ; doesn't tell MySQL that this command is over.

```
DELIMITER $$

[your code here]

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have added 
DELIMITER $$
[my code]
END $$
DELIMITER;
and I get an even bigger error. And my phpMyAdmin have delimiter option, and it's set to ";".